# having issues installing libraries using the 'conda' command after installing anaconda

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, conda, jupyter

i am using macOS. heres what my terminal looks like :

```
installation finished.
==> Changing ownership of paths required by anaconda with sudo; the password may
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
  anaconda was successfully installed!
conda install seaborn
zsh: command not found: conda
```

> "It appears that the conda command is not recognized in your terminal,
> which suggests that Anaconda's bin directory might not be in your
> system's PATH variable.
>
> To resolve this issue, you'll need to ensure that Anaconda's bin
> directory is added to your PATH so that you can access the conda
> command from any directory in your terminal."

heres what chatgpt had suggested. i cannot find 'anaconda" or 'miniconda' in my finder

Comment: It seems like Anaconda or Miniconda might not be installed in the standard location or there might be an issue with the PATH variable. Let's try to locate Anaconda or Miniconda in your system using the terminal. Could you please run the following command in your terminal and let me know the output?

```bash
find / -name "anaconda" -o -name "miniconda" 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: ' find / -type d -name "anaconda" 2>/dev/null

/usr/local/Caskroom/anaconda
' this is what it says